# Unable to execute testcase by hardcoding date to constructor

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have written a testcase for my java daoImpl class by mocking connection object, however, here is the twist. I have been hardcoding values so that i can compare these records with the records that i am getting from database and assert them finally.

```
Error: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The constructor Employee(String, String, String, String, String, String, int, int, String, int, boolean, int) is undefined
    The constructor Employee(String, String, String, String, String, String, int, int, String, int, boolean, int) is undefined

at com.cerner.devcenter.dao.junit.OrganizationDaoImplTest.testGetAllEmployeeDetails(OrganizationDaoImplTest.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Testclass:

```
public class OrganizationDaoImplTest {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Session session;
    private Query query;
    private OrganizationDaoImpl organizationDaoObj;

    String organizationId = "DevCenter01";
    boolean isActive = true;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        sessionFactory = mock(SessionFactory.class);
        session = mock(Session.class);
        query = mock(Query.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAllEmployeeDetails() throws ParseException {
        String hql = "from Employee where Organization_Id = organizationId and IsActive = isActive";
        List<Employee> expectedEmployeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        expectedEmployeeList
                .add(new Employee("AD042997", "Anitha", "D", "AD042999", new SimpleDateFormat("2015-02-12"),
                        "DevCenter01", "anitha@cerner.com", 805678993, 987652134, "C-1234", 7, true, 1));
        expectedEmployeeList.add(new Employee("AS042987", "Asha", "S", "AD042999",
                "DevCenter01", "asha@cerner.com", 434343434, 676990909, "C-4567", 7, true, 3));
        expectedEmployeeList
                .add(new Employee("HN099239", "Heena", "N", "AD042999",
                        "DevCenter01", "heena@cerner.com", 873847399, 486584658, "C-7432", 7, true, 7));

        organizationDaoObj = new OrganizationDaoImpl();
        Mockito.when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(session);
        Mockito.when(session.createQuery(hql)).thenReturn(query);
        Mockito.when(query.list()).thenReturn(expectedEmployeeList);
        List<Employee> actualEmployeeList = organizationDaoObj.getAllEmployeeDetails();
        assertNotNull(actualEmployeeList);
    }
}
```

Here the date is being treated as String instead of Date, i tried using just Date, SimpleDateFormat, both doesn't seem to work.

My constructor:

```
public Employee(String employeeId, String firstName, String lastName, String reportingManagerId, SimpleDateFormat dateOfJoining,
            String organizationId, String emailId, int mobileNumber, int officePhoneNo, String seatLocation,
            int jobLevel, boolean isActive, int id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.reportingManagerId = reportingManagerId;
        this.dateOfJoining = dateOfJoining;
        this.organizationId = organizationId;
        this.emailId = emailId;
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
        this.officePhoneNo = officePhoneNo;
        this.seatLocation = seatLocation;
        this.jobLevel = jobLevel;
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }
```

can anyone help on this??

Answer (score 0):

In these 2 lines,

```
    expectedEmployeeList.add(new Employee("AS042987", "Asha", "S", "AD042999",
            "DevCenter01", "asha@cerner.com", 434343434, 676990909, "C-4567", 7, true, 3));
    expectedEmployeeList
            .add(new Employee("HN099239", "Heena", "N", "AD042999",
                    "DevCenter01", "heena@cerner.com", 873847399, 486584658, "C-7432", 7, true, 7));
```

you have missed out the `SimpleDateFormat` parameter for the constructor.

Comment: That was just a trial by adding SimpleDateformat, even after adding Dateformat to 2nd, 3rd record, its failing with the same error